# Looking for Python framework to build a web interface for an AV engine

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, frameworks

I want to build a web application use Python for an antivirus engine. Actually I'm looking for a Python framework, I've not used any framework in python but i have enough experience to work with web programming and also python. How do I go about choosing a web application framework in python?

Just to be clear: there out a framework in Ruby on Rails [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info) which good for me, but i'm looking something in Python.

I would really appreciated if someone help me.

Comment: so you need an admin plugin for some python framework right?

Comment: Actually I need both a Python framework and an admin plugin if that framework doesn't have built-in.

Comment: Django itself will be more than enough in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) would be your choice. So far I've seen in other threads, Django's built-in admin panel will do what the `ActiveAdmin` for RoR can do for you.

If you're not satisfied with the django's built in admin you can plugin custom admin interfaces from any one of these, [Django-Packages-Admin](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/admin-interface/)

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest you take a look at [**Django**](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  It has a good deal of Docs and support.